# How to split file based on size linux

Tags: linux

I have a big [fasta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) file that is ~ 1 GiB of size. How can I split it on **n** MiB size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy solution using `split` command.

```
$ split -b 10MiB big.fsa
$ ls -lh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lukas lukas 870M Jun 26 13:46 big.fsa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xab
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xac
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xad
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xae
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xaf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xag
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xah
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xai
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xaj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xal
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xam
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xan
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xao
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xaq
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xas
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lukas lukas  10M Jun 26 14:05 xat
```

After that I renamed spited files with `rename` command by adding **.fsa** extension to all of them.

```
$ rename s/$/.fsa/ x*
```